# Programmatically setting a silverlight multi-select list box

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Is it possible to programatically set the values of a silverlight list box when the selection mode is "multiple"?  The "SelectedItems" property is not settable, 
and "SelectedIndex" only works when the selection mode is "single".

Answer (score 2):

Add items to SelectedItems collection:

```
myListBox.SelectedItems.Clear();
foreach(var item in selection)
    myListBox.SelectedItems.Add(item);
```